# Change textbox value using dropdown selected in php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have texbox and dropdown list which is populated from mysql database.I want to change textbox value using dropdown list, without refreshing the page.
Here is my code and Thanks in Advance.

```
<select name="select" id="dropdownlist1">
     <option id="0">-- Select the Company --</option>
           <?php
              require("dbcon.php");

        $getallcompanies = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ifcandetails6");

        while($viewallcompanies = mysql_fetch_array($getallcompanies)){
             ?>
 <option id="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcuid']; ?>"><?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcname'] ?></option>
                <?php
                      }
                  ?>
              </select>
```

Here is my Input field code:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" value="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcname']?>" disabled/>
```

Comment: `mysql_* ` is **EVIL**. Please google it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  following

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdownlist1").change(function(){
        $("#field1").val($(this).val());
    });
   });
```

As you can do it on front side itself, you dont need to change in your PHP code. Add the following code on DOM ready.

Comment: @MuhammedParveezKhushaali , if it solves your problem , you can accept answer.

Comment: i want to retrieve the saved data from database using the dropdown list.. but in this code i am getting the same value in inputbox what i am selecting in dropdown list..

Comment: But you told `.I want to change textbox value using dropdown list.` Please First clarify the Question by editing it. There is Edit button.