# Dropdown Selected value in Textbox PHP

Tags: php, dropdown

***Possible solution given in other question is not working here...

Hi I want to select value from dropdown and fetch in Textbox

This below code is fetching value from database but it is not putting in textbox. textbox below is named as emp_number and name of my dropdown is dealer

Please have a look

```
<?php


include 'connect-db.php';

//mysql_select_db("my", $con);
$s=mysql_query("select * from employees order by emp_number asc "); 
?>
   Select Employee Number:

   <select name="dealer" id="dealer" onchange='updateMyText()'>
   <option value="">---- Select employee Number -----</option>

    <?php
  while($dd=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dd['emp_id'] ?>"><?php echo $dd['emp_number']       ?></option>
 <?php
}
    ?>                  
</select>

<html>
<head>
        <title>PHP insertion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/insert.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navcss.css" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    /*$('#dealer').change(function () {
         $("#emp_number").val($(this).val());*/
             function updateMyText()
{
var dd = document.getElementById("dealer");
var ddtext = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById('emp_number').value = ddtext;
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="maindiv">
                    <br />
                    <label>Employee Number:</label>
                <br />
                <input class="input" type="text" name="emp_number" value="" />
                </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change textbox value using dropdown selected in php and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233266/change-textbox-value-using-dropdown-selected-in-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"document.getElementById('emp_number').value"--mistake.

Your javascript should be like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*$('#dealer').change(function () {
     $("#emp_number").val($(this).val());*/
function updateMyText()
{
var dd = document.getElementById("dealer");
var ddtext = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementsByName('emp_number')[0].value=ddtext;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Superb! Worked :) Thankie –

Comment: Not at all. Be healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Your statements does not ending syntax ";"

```
<option value="<?php echo $dd['emp_id']; ?>"><?php echo $dd['emp_number'] ;?></option>
```

It should have thrown syntax error actually.

```
while($dd = mysqli_fetch_array($s))
{
 <option><?php echo $dd['emp_id'];?>|<?php echo $dd['emp_number']; ?></option>
```

}

Comment: No worries fr syntax I cleared it but still not fetching in TextBox

Comment: Then remove the value so that it takes what is in between the <option></option> tag as default value.

Comment: You may have to check your db resource variable. use mysqli instead of mysql                                                                                      $s=mysqli_query($con, "select * from employees order by emp_number asc "); 
?>

Comment: See in Dropdown values are fetched, so no issue is in DB.. Problem is that it is not fetching that value in textbox ...